# Nextcord on_application_command_error problem

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

So I migrated from discord.py to Nextcord 1 month ago but it brought me another problem...
I'm using slash commands instead of normal commands but i noticed lately no error message to user who uses mod commands without a specific permission or something i tried `on_application_command_error` it gave a error but in terminal
i tried to search the solution but no information yet...
Here's the code by the way

```
async def on_application_command_error(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, error: nextcord.DiscordException):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Command not found.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Missing required argument.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid argument.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Command is on cooldown. Please try again later.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have permission to use this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await interaction.response.send_message("I don't have permission to perform this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have the required role to use this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingRole):
        await interaction.response.send_message("I don't have the required role to perform this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        await interaction.response.send_message("This command cannot be used in a private message.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Only the bot owner can use this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingAnyRole):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have any of the required roles to use this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await interaction.response.send_message("This command is currently disabled.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while executing the command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while executing the command.")
    elif isinstance(error, nextcord.errors.Forbidden):
        await interaction.response.send_message("I don't have permission to perform this action.")
    elif isinstance(error, nextcord.errors.HTTPException):
        await interaction.response.send_message("An HTTP exception occurred.")
    elif isinstance(error, nextcord.errors.NotFound):
        await interaction.response.send_message("The requested resource was not found.")
    elif isinstance(error, nextcord.errors.DiscordServerError):
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred on the Discord server.")
    elif isinstance(error, nextcord.errors.ConnectionClosed):
        await interaction.response.send_message("The connection to Discord was closed.")
```

Can y'all help me with this

i tried ApplicationMissingPermissions but it has no attribute, i expected user to be notified that he has no specific permission or other errors but i got error on the terminal instead

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need `on_application_command_error` when using slash_command
try like

```
async def test(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
if interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
    #your code here
else:
    await interaction.send("missing permission" , ephemeral=True)
```

you can change the administrator to any permission on discord

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me, but thanks for trying